# Why DB response ( resultSets) are being divided in two splits in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I'm querying DB to get the response through Mule. Response are being populated, but not sure why it is being divided inside resultSet1 (if it is larger).

Could see here in logger, ResultSet1  end tag is `</custo` ( not completly finished as ), it is being extended with same Key(`XML_F5RYI-11YTR`) and there it is finished `mers>`.

1. Do I need to do any configuration settings in Mule DB level to propogate all the  resultSet1 in same level ?
2. Actually My ultimate aim is to extract the resultSet1, second logger MEL is extracting, but it not a complete ResultSet.Could you please suggest  an MEL dynamically to extract the ResultSet1 Complete payload.

Else suggest me how can I achieve the scenario.

Please find the message printed in logger

```
 DB Actual response:{updateCount1=4,resultSet1=[{XML_F5RYI-11YTR=<Customers><Customer1>John<Customer1>( removed multiple customers tags)<Customer6>Ganesh<Customer6></Custo},{XML_F5RYI-11YTR=mers>}],resultSet2[{SequenceNumber=94}],updateCount2=1, updateCount3=4}
```

Please find the config xml

```
<poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="SCC_DB" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call [Database Query here](1)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:stored-procedure>
    </poll>
    <logger message="DB Actual response:#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Extracted ResultSet1 Response:************#[payload.resultSet1[0]['XML_F5RYI-11YTR']]********" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Mule Version : 3.5.1

Please suggest where I'm wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Edited:

I have enabled Streaming = 'true' and Made Fetch Count = '10'. If I enabled Streaming, response propagated after DB as below

```
****  DB response:org.mule.module.db.internal.result.statement.CloseableMap@558351f4*****
```

After adding Transformer 'Byte Array to string', response as below

```
  **After Transformer:{updateCount1=0, resultSet1=org.mule.module.db.internal.result.resultset.ResultSetIterator@64df82c7, resultSet2=org.mule.module.db.internal.result.resultset.ResultSetIterator@e030a8e}**********
```

I have tried separating #[payload.resultSet1] in set Payload, even after I'm not able to provide the transformer to see the exact response. Could you please suggest the transformer to see the response of resultSet1.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector) says this:

> **Fetch Size** - 
>   Indicates how many rows should be fetched from the resultSet. This property is required when streaming is true, the default value is 10.

Try setting this to the maximum size you expect.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick response. I have enabled both streaming and fetch. But the response is not human readable. I have tried 'ByteArray to String', 'Dom to xml'. But Not able to read the resultSet1 response. Could you please suggest the possible options.

Comment: :In my case response is propagating( disable streaming) in resultSet1 correctly( without any transformer)  with two key value pair( by dividing the xml) in resultSet1, But Same Key for both inside the resultSet1 as seen in the logger.  Also I have tried diabling 'streaming' and enabling 'fetch Count' alone. But no hope.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an dom to xml and you can use a collection aggregator to join the splits

Comment: I have resolved this issue by writing custom transformer.