# Use Mule ESB to Parse MySQL Stored Procedure ResultSets

Tags: java, mysql, json, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm using Mule and having trouble getting the results from a MySQL stored procedure into JSON.

It 'works' if I leave the results as they come out - but it includes some unnecessary gumf in the data.  MySQL is returning two results - one a resultset of the actual data I want, and one an `UpdateCount` (which will always be zero, it'll always return the results of a single select statement). These are being placed in the payload as a Hashmap, represented as follows:

```
{resultSet1=[{Rounds=15, Division=1, Season=2012, Type=League, Split=null, Name=DIVISION 1, ID=1}, {Rounds=14, Division=2, Season=2012, Type=League, Split=null, Name=DIVISION 2, ID=2}, {Rounds=14, Division=3, Season=2012, Type=League, Split=null, Name=DIVISION 3, ID=3}], updateCount1=0}
```

When I try to convert the above to JSON it works but it prints out everything.

What I want to do is get just the content of the square brackets after `resultSet1`.  I've tried doing a "Set Payload" before my Object-to-JSON control but can't quite get it to work.

`#[payload[0]]` gives a `NullPayload`, as does `#[payload[0][resultSet1]]` and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: You can find the answer here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526065/how-to-extract-the-value-of-resultset-returned-from-jdbc-response-via-mel-mule

Comment: I saw that earlier and tried it out, which is how I got to the above. After going through the steps again, I realise I just didn't need the [0], which is where that answer confused me.
Having said that, it's still spitting out a string surrounded by square braces when I convert to JSON and I don't think (?) this is valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `#[payload['resultSet1'][0]]` or `#[payload['resultSet1'].get(0)]`

Comment: I'm returning a list of competitions, if I do that I just get the first competition back.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found to work was a combination of the comment from Anirban pointing to [How to Extract the value of resultSet returned from JDBC response (Via MEL) Mule ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526065/how-to-extract-the-value-of-resultset-returned-from-jdbc-response-via-mel-mule) and rewriting the payload by concatenating stuff around it.

I set the payload to `payload['resultSet1']` before the Object to JSON transformer, then after the transformer I re-set the payload to `#['{\"competitions\": ' + payload +'}']`